# Ошибка при XSL преобразовании

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xslt, xsl

Я попробовала создать XSL элементы в `<div id="content">`

```js
function CreateXml() {
  content.innerHTML = `<?xml version="1.0"?>`;
}
//создание xsl:stylesheet
function CreateStylesheet(jsonObj) {
  var stylesheet = document.createElement("xsl:stylesheet");
  for (var prop of jsonObj['Attributes']) {
    stylesheet.setAttribute(prop['name'], prop['value']);
  }
  $(stylesheet).attr({
    "version": "1.0",
    "xmlns:n1": "urn:hl7-org:v3",
    "xmlns:n2": "urn:hl7-org:v3/meta/voc",
    "xmlns:voc": "urn:hl7-org:v3/voc",
    "xmlns:xsl": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  });
  content.appendChild(stylesheet);
  //создание xsl:output
  var output = document.createElement("xsl:output");
  $(output).attr({
    "method": "html",
    "indent": "yes",
    "version": "4.01",
    "encoding": "utf-8",
    "doctype-public": "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  });
  stylesheet.appendChild(output);
  //создание xsl:variable
  var variable = document.createElement("xsl:variable");
  variable.setAttribute('name', 'tableWidth');
  variable.textContent = "50%";
  stylesheet.appendChild(variable);
  // создание xsl:variable
  var variable = document.createElement("xsl:variable");
  variable.setAttribute('name', 'title');
  stylesheet.appendChild(variable);
  // создание choose
  var choose = document.createElement("xsl:choose");
  variable.appendChild(choose);
  // создание when
  var when = document.createElement("xsl:when");
  when.setAttribute('test', InputSymbol(jsonObj['Children'][5]['Element']['Xpath'], '/n1:', 'n1:'));
  choose.appendChild(when);
  // создание value-of 
  var value_of = document.createElement("xsl:value-of");
  value_of.setAttribute('select', InputSymbol(jsonObj['Children'][5]['Element']['Xpath'], '/n1:', 'n1:'));
  when.appendChild(value_of);
  }
```

и так далее. XSL структура отображается в DOM инспекторе:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:identity="urn:hl7-ru:identity" xmlns:address="urn:hl7-ru:address" xmlns:fias="urn:hl7-ru:fias" version="1.0" xmlns:n1="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:n2="urn:hl7-org:v3/meta/voc"
  xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:variable name="tableWidth">50%</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="title">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:title">
        <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:title"></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:text>от</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
          <xsl:with-param name="date" select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:effectiveTime/@value"></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="presicion" select="8"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>Clinical Document</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/n1:ClinicalDocument"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/n1:ClinicalDocument">
    <html>

    <head>
      <style>
        table.outer {
          width: 100%;
          cellspacing: 0;
          cellpadding: 0;
          border: solid 1px #999999;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        
        td.outer,
        th.outer {
          font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          border: solid 1px #999999;
          color: #003366;
        }
        
        th.outer {
          background: #EEEEEE;
        }
        
        td.outter {
          background: #fff;
        }
        
        table.Sections {
          border: none;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
          margins: 0, 0, 0, 0;
          padding: 0, 0, 0, 0;
          cellspacing: 0;
        }
        
        h2 {
          font: bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          color: #333333;
          text-align: left;
        }
        
        td.SectionTitle {
          border-top: solid 1px #999999;
          font: 12px Helvetica, sans-serif;
          background: #EEEEEE;
          text-align: left;
        }
        
        td.SubSectionTitle {
          border: none;
          font: 12px Helvetica, sans-serif;
          text-align: right;
          vertical-align: top;
          padding-right: 5px;
          padding-top: 4px;
        }
        
        td.Rest {
          border-top: none;
          border-right: none;
          border-bottom: none;
          border-left: none;
          font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          color: #003366;
          text-align: bottom;
        }
        
        tr {
          vertical-align: top;
        }
        
        table.inner {
          cellspacing: 1;
          cellpadding: 5;
          border: none;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        
        table.inner th,
        table.inner td,
        table.inner tr {
          font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          color: #003366;
          border: none;
          padding: 2px 5px;
        }
        
        th.inner {
          background: #EEEEEE;
        }
        
        td.inner {
          background: #fff;
        }
        
        .col1 {
          width: 15%;
        }
        
        .col2 {
          width: 85%;
        }
        
        .tdCol1 {
          text-align: left;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        .tdCol2 {
          text-align: left;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <table class="outer" width="100%">
        <col width="30%">
        <col width="70%">
        <tr class="outer">
          <th class="outer" width="30%" align="center">Медицинская организация:</th>
          <td class="outer">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization[not(@nullFlavor)]"><strong>Полное наименование медицинской организации: </strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:name"></xsl:value-of><br></xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:addr[not(@nullFlavor)]"><strong>Адрес: </strong>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:addr"></xsl:apply-templates><br></xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:identity:Props/n1:identity:Ogrn[not(@nullFlavor)]"><strong>ОГРН:</strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:identity:Props/n1:identity:Ogrn"></xsl:value-of><br></xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:identity:Props/n1:identity:Ogrnip[not(@nullFlavor)]"><strong>ОГРНИП:</strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:identity:Props/n1:identity:Ogrnip"></xsl:value-of><br></xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:identity:Props/n1:identity:Okpo[not(@nullFlavor)]"><strong>ОКПО:</strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:identity:Props/n1:identity:Okpo"></xsl:value-of><br></xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:identity:Props/n1:identity:Okato[not(@nullFlavor)]"><strong>ОКАТО:</strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:identity:Props/n1:identity:Okato"></xsl:value-of><br></xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/id[@root='1.2.643.5.1.13.2.1.1.1504.101'][not(@nullFlavor)]"><strong>Лицензия: </strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/id[@root='1.2.643.5.1.13.2.1.1.1504.101']/@extension"></xsl:value-of><text>Дата регистрации: </text>
                <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/id[@root='1.2.643.5.1.13.2.1.1.1504.101']/@assigningAuthorityName"></xsl:value-of><br></xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:telecom[not(@nullFlavor)]"><strong>Контакты: </strong>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:providerOrganization/n1:telecom"></xsl:apply-templates><br></xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <h1 align="center">
        <xsl:value-of select="$title"></xsl:value-of>
      </h1>
      <table class="outer" width="100%">
        <col width="30%">
        <col width="70%">
        <tr class="outer">
          <th class="outer" width="30%" align="center">Пациент</th>
          <td>/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:patient/n1:name</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>

    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Но при преобразовании XML файла с помощью созданного XSL возникает ошибка:

> Ошибка загрузки таблицы стилей: Ошибка разбора выражения XPath, символ «:» здесь запрещён:

Не понимаю, что не так: либо в коде напортачено, либо таким способом создавать программно XSL нельзя